# Flask API on Heroku - <Response [503]> - JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python

I am trying to deploy my flask app on Heorku. The app is working fine on my local system, but when I am deploying the app on Heroku and testing, its giving me a Response <503>.
Attaching the code below

```
import requests
import json
import time
url = 'https://ner-spacy-2.herokuapp.com/'

text = 'MUMBAI: Office-based employees Hindustan Unilever ( HUL ) went work-from-home (WFH) mode March 17 itself, Rs 38,000-crore    FMCG    major framed new set protocols employees, area sales managers (ASMs) field force.   incident management team (IMT) — cross-functional steering committee — set lead multiple pillars Covid-19 readiness, 1,000 circle meetings (virtual meetings manager team) taken place cover'

data = json.dumps(text)
send_request = requests.post(url, data)
```

This is giving Response: 503

My build was successful in heroku. Find the flask app code below.

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import pickle

import en_core_web_md
nlp = en_core_web_md.load()

# app
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_ner_tags():
    try:
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        valid_labels = ['PERSON','NORP','FAC','ORG','LOC','PRODUCT','EVENT','WORK_OF_ART','LAW','LANGUAGE']
        geo_label = ['GPE']
        cardinality_labels = ['PERCENT','MONEY','QUANTITY']
        
        article_tags = []
        geo_tags = []
        cardinal_tags = []

        doc = nlp(data)

        for X in doc.ents:
          if X.label_ in valid_labels:
            article_tags.append(X.text)
          elif X.label_ in geo_label:
            geo_tags.append(X.text)
          elif X.label_ in cardinality_labels:
            cardinal_tags.append(X.text)

        article_tags = list(dict.fromkeys(article_tags))
        geo_tags = list(dict.fromkeys(geo_tags))
        cardinal_tags = list(dict.fromkeys(cardinal_tags))

        try:
        # fuzzy matching to remove duplicates
          article_tags = list(process.dedupe(article_tags, threshold=80, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
        except:
          article_tags = article_tags

        output = {'tags': [article_tags, geo_tags, cardinal_tags]}
        # return jsonify(results=output)
        return jsonify(results=output)
    
   except Exception as e:
        return jsonify(results=e)

app.run()
```

Comment: your description not full you send `data` but data you have in variable `text` or have error

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add a line, now added it but the error is same

Answer (score 1):

In your request, you just send text not JSON.

````
import requests
import json
import time
url = 'https://ner-spacy-2.herokuapp.com/'

text = {'MUMBAI': 'Office-based employees Hindustan Unilever ( HUL ) went work-from-home (WFH) mode March 17 itself, Rs 38,000-crore    FMCG    major framed new set protocols employees, area sales managers (ASMs) field force.   incident management team (IMT) — cross-functional steering committee — set lead multiple pillars Covid-19 readiness, 1,000 circle meetings (virtual meetings manager team) taken place cover'}

send_request = requests.post(url, json=text)```
````

Comment: @VishalSingh it is same... I forgot to add this in line the question that I posted on Stackover flow, but included it in the original code. Thanks!

Comment: your code is not correct:
because you should  convert `text` to `dict`
if you just do `data = json.dumps(text)` it will be just text
`print(type(data))`